# Remove last segment of Request.Url

Tags: c#

I would like to remove the last segment of `Request.Url`, so for instance...

```
http://www.example.com/admin/users.aspx/deleteUser
```

would change to

```
http://www.example.com/admin/users.aspx
```

I would prefer linq but accept any solution that efficiently works.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the URI contains metacharacters, query strings or parameters; e.g. `http://www.example.com/admin/users.aspx/deleteUser?alpha=for%27?beta=%5F%39`?

Comment: great question, ideally I would keep them, just removing the last segment of the path.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to parse the URI - you can access all the segments using the `Segments` property and rebuild the URI without the last segment.

```
var uri = new Uri(myString);

var noLastSegment = string.Format("{0}://{1}", uri.Scheme, uri.Authority);

for(int i = 0; i < uri.Segments.Length - 1; i++)
{
   noLastSegment += uri.Segments[i];
}

noLastSegment = noLastSegment.Trim("/".ToCharArray()); // remove trailing `/`
```

As an alternative to getting the scheme and host name, as suggested by Dour High Arch in his comment:

```
var noLastSegment = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, 
                                      UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
```

Comment: I suggest `uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, ...)` rather than `uri.Scheme`, as the former handles ports and includes the `://`.

Comment: ...or at least `uri.Authority` instead of `DnsSafeHost`

Comment: @spender - Can you elucidate me on the difference and reasoning?

Comment: Uri.Authority includes a port ( e.g. `someHost:81` ) if the port is non-standard for that particular scheme. Of course, copying into a UriBuilder and changing what's needed (rather than recomposing the whole uri string) seems less error-prone.

Answer (score 17):

Much the same as @Oded's answer, but using a UriBuilder instead:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/admin/users.aspx/deleteUser");
var newSegments = uri.Segments.Take(uri.Segments.Length - 1).ToArray();
newSegments[newSegments.Length-1] = 
    newSegments[newSegments.Length-1].TrimEnd('/');
var ub=new UriBuilder(uri);
ub.Path=string.Concat(newSegments);
//ub.Query=string.Empty;  //maybe?
var newUri=ub.Uri;
```

Answer (score 11):

To remove the last segment of Request.Url it is enough to subtract from absolute uri the length of last segment.

```
string uriWithoutLastSegment = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Remove(
  Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Length - Request.Url.Segments.Last().Length );
```

Comment: Please make the answer more detailed, and note, that your answer must be better (by some meanings) than the existing one.

Comment: I hope that now the only line of my code understandable and you, Victor Polevoy.

Comment: Your answer is much better now. Avoid code-only answers in the future.

Comment: I can see ho this look easier, but this way you don't take into account any querystring paramters, which will be trailing the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri. Not really a catch all solution.

Answer (score 2):

I find manipulating Uri's fairly annoying, and as the other answers are quite verbose, here's my two cents in the form of an extension method.

As a bonus you also get a replace last segement method. Both methods will leave querystring and other parts of the url intact.

```cs
public static class UriExtensions
{
    private static readonly Regex LastSegmentPattern = 
        new Regex(@"([^:]+://[^?]+)(/[^/?#]+)(.*$)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);        

    public static Uri ReplaceLastSegement(this Uri me, string replacement)
        => me != null ? new Uri(LastSegmentPattern.Replace(me.AbsoluteUri, $"$1/{replacement}$3")) : null;

    public static Uri RemoveLastSegement(this Uri me)
        => me != null ? new Uri(LastSegmentPattern.Replace(me.AbsoluteUri, "$1$3")) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the trivial solution would be to iterate char by char from the end of the string towards its beginning and search for the first '/' to come (I guess that also came into your mind).

Try this:

```
string url = "http://www.example.com/admin/users.aspx/deleteUser";

for (int i = url.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (url[i] == '/') return url.Substring(0, i - 1);
}
```

Comment: better/cleaner is to use 'String.LastIndexOf'

Comment: Couldn't there be a / in the query string?