# Is the current page the child of a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to detect if the current page uri is contains an actual page name rather than simply the default for that directory / no child path.

For example if I were to browse to a directory default it would be:

```
www.domain.com/directory
```

However, I need to detect when the page url/uri is that of a child page eg:

```
www.domain.com/directory/page.aspx
```

or

```
www.domain.com/directory/something
```

What is the most efficient way to do this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to figure out how to differentiate "/directory/childPage" from "/directory/subdirectory". Then just trim the last segment of "path with child page" using 
[Uri.Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx).

```
var pageUri  = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/directory/page.aspx");
var pageName = pageUri.Segments[pageUri.Segments.Length - 1];
```

Similar question - [Remove last segment of Request.Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529326/remove-last-segment-of-request-url)

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks, I'll go give it a try. I dont recall ever coming across segments before. Always good to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.AbsolutePath` or the `.LocalPath` of the `Request.Url` and check if its ends to `Default.aspx`, for example

```
if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/default.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
  // you are browsing the directory.
}
```

Comment: That wouldnt do it, since the default wont be present on a uri with just a directory eg the first example in my OP. This is due to the nature of the 3rd party application which is integrated with Dynamics. So there is also rewriting going on in the background.

Comment: @PhillHealey Do you test it, or you suppose that it not work ? because even if you do not see it on the url, and even if you make rewrite, the deault.aspx is shown on this calls

Comment: Sorry, how would this work if the defauly page is not physically named "default.aspx" ?

Comment: The default page in reality could be called absolutely anything. So without knowing the name it wouldnt be possible to check for it with your method. Especially since the 'page' is a masterpage that could be used for various directories. So it wouldnt work without manually checking for all the manuallt added potential directory / uri structure of all possible options.