# Remove the last part of string URL using C#

Tags: c#

I need to access a json file from `http://localhost/sampleprogram/commonfile/data/sample.json` this URL.

However, the default index.html is in `http://localhost/sampleprogram/src/index.html`

In C# code, how can I cut the last part of the URL:

`http://localhost/sampleprogram/src` to `http://localhost/sampleprogram`

Any method can do this?

Comment: Check out the `Uri` class

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529326/remove-last-segment-of-request-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know exactly what part you want to remove the following should work.

```
string URL = "http://localhost/sampleprogram/src";
string newURl = URL.Remove(URL.IndexOf("/src"));
```

This will it make you so you won't need to count the characters.

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'remove()' - and 'Remove()' doesn't take 'string' as parameter. So this code won't even compile

Comment: Hi, i've edited it to fix the mistake it should work now, it was missing the path.IndexOf method call inside of remove, which will automatically get the index of the characters.

Comment: the path is undefined when i compile

Comment: I've edited the solution and ran it produces the right results now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://localhost/sampleprogram/src";
var newUrl = url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating with a string then you can remove it by

```
string yourURL = "http://localhost/sampleprogram/src";
string newURL = yourURL.Remove(30);
//expected result http://localhost/sampleprogram
```

Where this will remove all string after character 30. Also you can use split function at '/' and remove the last element

```
string yourURL = "http://localhost/sampleprogram/src";

// split string 
string[] result = yourURL.Split('/');
result = result.SkipLast(1).ToArray();
string newURL = String.Join('/', result);
```

Best

Comment: I get the error when compile
 error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

on the .Split("/")

Comment: I updated my asnswer just replace "/" by '/' (as a character)

Comment: I tested it on my side and it works fine. please inform me if all things goes right