# Do I have a chance to get the url by parsing the parameter from the incoming request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc web application developed with .Net Core 6.0. I want to get the parameterless version of the url according to the request from the user. For example:
From request https://www.mywebsite.com/Product/UpdateProduct/20
I want to get the result of /Product/UpdateProduct

```
var link = Request.Path.Value;
```

This action gives me the feeling of /Product/Update Product/22

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What do you mean by "gives me the feeling of"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the following post for possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529326/remove-last-segment-of-request-url